# Turn Obj-sequence into FBX file for Unity?

Tags: animation, mesh, export, unity, .fbx

I have a sequence of objs of an object deforming, each of which has the same number of vertices and faces, that I would like to be able to put together into an animation and then export as an fbx that could be brought into unity.

I've used 'Stop Motion Add-on' to import the sequence which seems to have worked, I can play the animation, but when I try to export as an fbx I just get a single object of whatever frame I was on with no animation attached to it.

is there some special way I need to export it so that the animation is part of the fbx file?

Comment: I'm not sure if fbx supports object sequences. The .mdd .pc2 and .abc files support them. Not sure about mdd and pc2 but there is an [alembic importer](https://github.com/unity3d-jp/AlembicForUnity) for unity.

Comment: ok, do you know of  method for exporting the obj sequence as an alembic?

Comment: Blender releases include alembic support. When you choose to [export to alembic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/pipeline/alembic.html) you can choose to only export selected objects and what frame range to export.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Import OBJ Sequence As Shape Keys blender add-on from [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-import-obj-sequence-as-shape-keys-on-one-object/575402). As described by you and shown in the video on the add-on page, it seems to work in your case.

Download the add-on from [here](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/3X/9/4/9412aa985d01f23858d26787644539f55aed67a5.zip) (Windows).

Initial setup is as follows:

```
Select “File” - “Import” - “Wavefront.obj” from the “file” menu and navigate to the directory which holds the OBJ sequence
Select the first OBJ file in the sequence and click “Import OBJ”.
Select the newly imported object in the 3D view or the outliner
Select the “Object Data” tab in the main properties panel
In the “Shape keys” section, click the “Add shape key to object” button (+)
Uncheck the “Relative” Checkbox and set the interpolation dropdown menu to “Linear”
Change the current frame in the timeline to “0” and set a keyframe for “Evaluation time” (as “0”)
Change the current frame on the timeline to “1000”
Enter “10000” as evaluation time. (it seems to go in steps of 10 strangely!), then set a keyframe for “Evaluation time”
Change to the graph editor window, then select the curve for “Evaluation time”
Select “Key” - “Interpolation Mode” - “Linear” from the graph editor menu.
Change back to the 3D view.
```

Once you done that, you use the script to import the sequence:

```
Select “File” - “Import” - “OBJ as Shapekey” from the “file” menu and navigate to the directory which holds the OBJ sequence.
Select the rest of the sequence(all except for the first obj file in the sequence) and click “Import OBJ as Shape Keys”.
Wait as it loads the sequence…
```

A [video tutorial](http://www.blenderinmotion.com/controlling-blender-physics.php)..

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you added a bit about how to use that addon.